# Getting error while running create secrets manager command using aws cli

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli, aws-secrets-manager

I am trying to create one secrets manager using aws cli command. The command I tried is

```
aws secretsmanager create-secret \
    --name sample_auth_aws_secret1 \
    --description "My test secret created with the CLI." \
    -- tags {"env":"dev","sample=test"} \
    --secret-string "{\"clientId\":\"sample123\",\"secret\":\"wjwjwjwjwjwjwjsjsjsj\"}"
```

I am getting error

```
usage: aws [options] <command> <subcommand> [<subcommand> ...] [parameters]
To see help text, you can run:

  aws help
  aws <command> help
  aws <command> <subcommand> help

Unknown options: env:dev, sample=test, --secret-string, {"clientId":"sample123","secret":"wjwjwjwjwjwjwjsjsjsj"}, tags
```

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two problems in your command.

1. use --tags instead -- tags
2. key value are not in correct json format.

please use below command

```
aws secretsmanager create-secret \
--name sample_auth_aws_secret1 \
--description "My test secret created with the CLI." \
--tags '{"Key":"CostCenter","Value":"12345"}' \
--secret-string "{\"clientId\":\"sample123\",\"secret\":\"wjwjwjwjwjwjwjsjsjsj\"}"
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a space here between the `--` and `tags`:

```
-- tags {"env":"dev","sample=test"} \
```

It should be:

```
--tags {"env":"dev","sample=test"} \
```

---

Also, you're syntax is totally wrong for setting tags. You're using `:` in the first tag, and `=` in the 2nd tag, but your overall syntax is wrong anyway. I suggest looking at [the documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/secretsmanager/create-secret.html) and copying their examples.

It should be:

```
--tags [{"Key":"env","Value":"dev"},{"Key":"sample","Value":"test"}] \
```

Comment: Thank you Mark ,but still getting error 
Error parsing parameter '--tags': Expected: '=', received: 'EOF' for input:
env:dev

Comment: @Chintamani see my updated answer

Comment: Hi Mark ,I tried this ,but getting invalid json .My command is aws secretsmanager create-secret \
    --name sample_auth_aws_secret1 \
    --description "My test secret created with the CLI." \
 --tags [{"Key":"env","Value":"dev"},{"Key":"sample","Value":"test"}] \
    --secret-string "{\"clientId\":\"sample123\",\"secret\":\"wjwjwjwjwjwjwjsjsjsj\"}" .getting Error parsing parameter '--tags': Invalid JSON:
[Key:env,Key:sample]

Answer (score 0):

It has to do with the `tags` that you are passing.  You need a proper Key and Value assignment.

Try passing the working shorthand:

`--tags Key="env",Value="dev" Key="sample",Value="test" \`